# Vim: text auto-wrapping doesn't wrap to the next line when it reaches the `textwidth` maximum

Tags: vim

Below is my `vimrc` configuration. I want the text to be wrapped to the next line when it reaches the `textwidth` maximum.

```
syntax on
set tabstop=4
set linebreak
set wrap
filetype indent off
set paste
set tw=120
set ruler
```

I'm using Macbook pro 2014, El Capitan, iterm2.

I have also tried `set formatoptions+=cqtrol`.

Comment: 1. ***NEVER*** put `set paste` in your `vimrc`. 2. `set wrap` does exactly the opposite of what you want.

Comment: Thanks. I have taken out wrap. But still words after 120 length cannot go to new lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the effect of `set paste`. From the Vim help for `paste`:

```
When the 'paste' option is switched on (also when it was already on):
    ...
    - 'formatoptions' is used like it is empty
```

The default value for `formatoptions` is `vt`, where `t` is required for auto-wrapping:

```
t       Auto-wrap text using textwidth
```

Refer to `:help fo-table`.

So you should remove `set paste` from your configuration, or unset it *temporarily* via `set nopaste` command.

I recommend keeping `nopaste` by default, i.e. removing `set paste`, and using the `pastetoggle` option instead. For example, the following command configures `F12` key for toggling the paste mode.

```
set pastetoggle=<F12>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It seems to make sense to me. But I have tried and the problem still exists.